# 3D tiling of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Provided a 1D array as `a`:

```
a=np.arange(8)
```

I would like it to be reproduced in a 3D scheme in order to have such shape `(n1, len(a), n3)`.
Is there any working way to obtain this via `np.tile`? It seems trivial, but trying:

```
np.shape(  np.tile(a, (n1,1,n3))  )
```

or

```
np.shape(  np.tile( np.tile(a, (n1,1)), (1,1,n2) )  )
```

I never obtain what I need, being the resulting shapes `(n1, 1, len(a)*n3)` or `(1, n1, len(a)*n3)`. 
Maybe it is me not understanding how `tile` works ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What's happening is that `a` is being made a 1x1x8 array before the tiling is applied.  You'll need to make `a` a 1x8x1 array and then call `tile`.

As [the documentation for `tile`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) notes:

> If `A.ndim < d`, `A` is promoted to be d-dimensional by prepending
>   new axes. So a shape (3,) array is promoted to (1, 3) for 2-D
>   replication, or shape (1, 1, 3) for 3-D replication. If this is not
>   the desired behavior, promote `A` to d-dimensions manually before
>   calling this function.

The easiest way to get the result you're after is to slice `a` with `None` (or equivalently, `np.newaxis`) to make it the correct shape.

As a quick example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(8)
result = np.tile(a[None, :, None], (4, 1, 5))
print result.shape
```